# storing dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Is it better to store dates in mysql in three columns or use just one column. Which one is faster. Also, if I just want to do inserts with todays date in format dd/mm/yy , how do I do that. and also how do I do selects with that. Also, lets say if I wanted to get results for all the wednesdays, how do I do that or lets say one date 25th of all the months and years, how do i do that.

Thanks People.

I am using PHP with Apache and Mysql.

What are the drawbacks of using the structure that I am proposing. I can easily get all the 25th by using the date table and I can get all the days using another column for days. How much difference would be there in the terms of speed between my proposed solution and using a DATE table?

Comment: you should refer to mysql documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, if I just want to do inserts with todays date in format dd/mm/yy ,how do I do that.

```
Well it depends on the format your date is passed in through your 
form but you are going to want to store your date in YYYY-mm-dd format.

INSERT INTO my_table (timefieldname) VALUES ( '$date' );
```

and also how do I do selects with that.

```
SELECT timefieldname FROM my_table;

//or you can format the date - this will give you month/day/year 01/01/2012
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timefieldname, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM my_table;
```

Also, lets say if I wanted to get results for all the wednesdays,

```
SELECT timefieldname FROM my_table WHERE DAYNAME(timefieldname) = 'Wednesday';
```

How do I do that or lets say one date 25th of all the months and years, how do i do that.

```
SELECT timefieldname FROM my_table WHERE DAY(timefieldname) = '25';
```

Comment: hey...thanks...btw...if i want to store dates in format of dd-mm-yyyy. can that be done?

Comment: Thanks! I don't think it can be done. When you try to insert the date in mm-dd-YYYY value it sets the value to 0000-00-00 in the database, at least when I tried it out. But you can change your date to the yyyy-mm-dd format before inserting it, and use DATE_FORMAT to get it out the way you want it. But in PHP you can convert the date to format you need for MySql: [http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php]

Answer (score 5):

You will want to use a proper column type, such as `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP`, depending on your needs.  They are built specifically to handle dates, and can more easily perform other functions (adding, comparing, etc.) that would be difficult to perform on 3 separate columns.

Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) for more info.

`DAYOFWEEK(date)` will give you a numeric representation for the day.  In your case, 4 = Wednesday.  `DAYOFMONTH(date)` will work for finding all 25th days of the month.

`DAYNAME(date)` will return the name of the weekday for date

Comment: If I want to find the records for all the wednesdays, how do i do that. Could you please help me with the sql. Also, after reading that I want to use DATE but I would need more reference to the sql. Please help me a little bit more...sorry for dragging this.

Comment: The link provided gives you the full reference you need to perform this function.  You are going to go farther by reading up and understanding the information yourself than having someone give you the answer.  You might get a quick answer today, but you will have gained nothing for the future.

Comment: Thanks for the advice...it is appreciated :). But I would really like the answer for today because it is bit late here in London. You don't have to give me the answer because I am being lazy, but it would be good if you did. Thanks

Comment: `select * from table where dayofweek(date) = 4;`

Comment: I defiantly second using a proper sql date column. Right now I'm having to normalize a bunch of dates (that my predicessor allowed to be free hand entered) because a user group now wants us to format the date using the EU format vs US time. So I have to go through the db looking for all of the ASAP's and July or other string times that a user might have put in. Had all of this been validated and entered as a datetime format everything would be so very much easier.

Comment: what do you mean by normalizing. Arent dates stored in three separate columns already normalised, since they are just ids

Answer (score 0):

You can free up having to pass dates from your codebase and let mysql insert them for you, provided they are time stamps:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD `timefieldname` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

It's not much of a speed boost, but it does reduce your need to code and validate variables passed to the database.